# Unable to start Spark application with Bahir

Tags: scala, apache-spark, activemq-classic, apache-bahir

I am trying to run a Spark application in Scala to connect to ActiveMQ. I am using Bahir for this purpose `format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")`. When I am using `Bahir2.2` in my `built.sbt` the application is running fine but on changing it to `Bahir3.0` or `Bahir4.0` the application is not starting and it is giving an error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream`
```

How to fix this? Is there an alternative of Bahir which I can use in my Spark-Structured-Streaming to connect to ActiveMQ topics?

EDIT:
my build.sbt

```
//For spark
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "2.4.0",
)

//Bahir
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-sql-streaming-mqtt" % "2.4.0"
```

Comment: show build.sbt ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: @Srinivas I have added my build.sbt

Comment: hadoop version ??

Comment: @Srinivas I am sorry, but I don't have Hadoop installed I am a beginner, before this I was testing Bahir2.2 and never encountered this error, do I now need to install Hadoop?

Comment: the error seems library versions are not matching or incompatability of hadoop.

Comment: I just fixed it by rolling back to version 2.3 of both spark and bahir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So it seems some kind of compatibility issue between `spark2.4` and `bahir2.4`. I fixed it by rolling back both of them to `ver 2.3`.

Here is my `build.sbt`

```
name := "sparkTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

//For spark
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.0" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "2.3.0",
//    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.3",
)

//Bahir
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-sql-streaming-mqtt" % "2.3.0"
```